# How do I log outgoing connections (meaning from server to client) using haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I'm running an haproxy server and was wondering what configuration exactly do I need in order to log out going connections (from my webserver to my client).

I'm currently logging incoming connections only (client to server).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You... don't.  Outgoing connections don't go via haproxy.  If you need to limit outgoing connections, use a perimeter firewall, and if you really, really need to log outgoing connections (why?), then either setup a full netflow logging system on your perimeter, or run everything through a proxy like squid (for HTTP(S)/FTP) or perhaps a socks proxy for other protocols.

Answer (score 2):

HAProxy is designed for many-to-few operation, where the 'few' are the network services behind it and are statically defined in the config file. Reversing the flow, few-to-many, simply won't work with HAProxy.

For that use something that is designed for that sort of operation, such as a Squid proxy or any number of commercial "track your employees browsing habits" perimeter products. Alternately, you could improve your network logging instead and grab net-flow data which will get all transactions.